# rTorrent init script not working

Tags: users, init.d, rtorrent, rutorrent

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu 14.04 box with rTorrent and ruTorrent. I've installed rTorrent and it launches just fine using my own user account.

I've created a new user account named rtorrent to run rTorrent.

```
sudo adduser --system --group rtorrent
```

Next I set up the config file `.rtorrent.rc` in `/home/rtorrent` and made rtorrent the owner of said file.

```
sudo chown rtorrent:rtorrent .rtorrent.rc
```

I would very much like for `rtorrent` to automatically start. I borrowed the below init script from [this guide](https://jes.sc/kb/rTorrent+ruTorrent-Seedbox-Guide.php):

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rtorrent
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/stop rtorrent daemon
### END INIT INFO

## Username to run rtorrent under, make sure you have a .rtorrent.rc in the
## home directory of this user!
USER="rtorrent"

## Absolute path to the rtorrent binary.
## run "which rtorrent"
RTORRENT="/usr/local/bin/rtorrent"

## Absolute path to the screen binary.
SCREEN="/usr/bin/screen"

## Name of the screen session, you can then "screen -r rtorrent" to get it back
## to the foreground and work with it on your shell.
SCREEN_NAME="rtorrent"

## Absolute path to rtorrent's PID file.
PIDFILE="/var/run/rtorrent.pid"

## Absolute path to rtorrent's XMLRPC socket.
SOCKET="/var/run/rtorrent/rpc.socket"

## Check if the socket exists and if it exists delete it.
delete_socket() {
if [[ -e $SOCKET ]]; then
rm -f $SOCKET
fi
}

case "$1" in
## Start rtorrent in the background.
start)
echo "Starting rtorrent."
delete_socket
start-stop-daemon --start --background --oknodo \
--pidfile "$PIDFILE" --make-pidfile \
--chuid $USER \
--exec $SCREEN -- -DmUS $SCREEN_NAME $RTORRENT
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
echo "Error: rtorrent failed to start."
exit 1
fi
echo "rtorrent started successfully."
;;

## Stop rtorrent.
stop)
echo "Stopping rtorrent."
start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --pidfile "$PIDFILE"
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
echo "Error: failed to stop rtorrent process."
exit 1
fi
delete_socket
echo "rtorrent stopped successfully."
;;

## Restart rtorrent.
restart)
"$0" stop
sleep 1
"$0" start || exit 1
;;

## Print usage information if the user gives an invalid option.
*)
echo "Usage: $0 [start|stop|restart]"
exit 1
;;

esac
```

Next:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/rtorrent
sudo update-rc.d rtorrent defaults 99
```

Sadly, after a reboot and doing

```
sudo top
```

`rtorrent` is nowhere to be seen. When I do

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rtorrent start
```

I receive the message that `rtorrent` has started, but I still can't find it when running `top`.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this question it dawned on me. My `.rtorrent.rc` file was not the same for both users. After fixing the config for the user rtorrent everything works.